# Any x86-64 Linux assembler?

Tags: linux, x86, development, assembly

I want to start learning assembly language, but all the googling didn't make any sense. I got some `Exec format error` and even used `wine` which is not good for understanding. So I wonder if anyone can tell what command line assembler will do on `x86-64` architecture and probably some hello world example for Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are quite a few assemblers available, including:

- [`gas`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html) (part of `binutils`, and supported by GCC) — this is available everywhere, and uses AT&T style;
- [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) (look for a `nasm` package in your distribution) — this supports Intel-style mnemonics;
- [Yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/) which is a rewrite of NASM (look for a `yasm` package);
- [fasm](https://flatassembler.net/), the flat assembler.

Here's a “Hello world” for `gas`:

```
    .global _start

    .text
_start:
    mov     $1, %rax
    mov     $1, %rdi
    mov     $hello, %rsi
    mov     $13, %rdx
    syscall

    mov     $60, %rax
    xor     %rdi, %rdi
    syscall

hello:
    .ascii  "Hello, world\n"
```

Save this to `hello.S`, and build it using `gcc -c hello.S && ld -o hello hello.o`.

The equivalent for NASM is:

```
    section .text
    global  _start

_start:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, hello
    mov     rdx, len
    syscall

    mov     rax, 60
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall

    hello   db "Hello, world",0x0A
    len     equ $ - hello
```

Save this as `hello.asm`, and build it using `nasm -felf64 hello.asm && ld -o hello hello.o`.

Answer (score 2):

NASM is a good assembler for Linux/Unix.
You can find plenty of examples from google for NASM 64-bit code.

For Centos you can install NASM with:

```
yum install nasm -y
```

For debian/ubuntu it's probably:

```
apt-get install nasm
```

Answer (score -2):

#### SASM

To edit files.

```
$ apt-get install sasm
```

#### NASM

To compile files.

```
$ apt-get install nasm
```